# Python: How to chain boolean tests to get False as soon as it gets the first False

Tags: python, boolean, short-circuiting, truthtable

After having a lot of trouble trying to reduce nested ifs (and a script that stopped working), I realized perhaps I am having the wrong idea of what and how boolean stuff works in python.

I had this (working fine but contorted):

```
if (not gotside):
    if (j > 1):
        if (j < a.shape[1] - 1):
            if a[i, j+unit]:
                print "only now I do stuff!"
```

And tried this (looking sreamlined by not working as desired):

```
if (not gotside) and (j > 1) and (j < a.shape[1] - 1) and a[i, j+unit]:
    print "I'm well tested but not so indented..."
```

Then I tried to use "or" instead of "and", but didn' work, because (later I found) when you use `x and y` or even `x or y` you get one of `x, y`, and not one of `True, False`, acording to docs.

So, I don't know how I can put a handful of tests one after another (preferrably in the same line, with boolean operators) in a way that the whole expression returns `False` as soon as the first test evaluates to False.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You are referring to short circuiting. Yes I believe in your streamlined example it should 'short circuit' the equation if gotside is true, hence not bother with the rest. If not, then maybe you need brackets to enclose all the rest of the checks into one set of parentheses.

Comment: Even though the boolean expressions may not return boolean values, when the result is evaluated in the boolean context, it is interpreted as you would expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example should work.

```
if x and y and z:
    ...
```

Should happen only if none of x, y and z evaluate to `False`, and in Python, `and` short-circuits, so will return the `False` value as soon as one item fails. We can show this quite easily:

```
>>> def test(n):
...     print("test", n)
...     return n
... 
>>> test(1) and test(2)
test 1
test 2
2
>>> test(0) and test(2)
test 0
0
>>> test(0) and test(2) and test(3)
test 0
0
>>> test(1) and test(0) and test(3)
test 1
test 0
0
```

Comment: Very interesting way of putting it. I think there is not much left to argue :o) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

I see your concern, but remember that whenever something is in an `if` statement in Python, it will be implicitly converted to `bool` for the conditional.  Thus while `3 or 2` returns `3` and `3 and 2` returns `2` when done stand-alone, saying `if 3 or 2` is actually equivalent to saying `if bool(3 or 2)`, so you will get the falsey or truey value of what the logic returns when used in a conditional regardless of what the boolean logic would return in other contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I have to agree with the others in saying that your example should be working as you intend. You're right that `x or y` returns one of x, y, but that object will be able to be evaluated as True or False. That is how python evaluates `if` statements. It should work as written because your expressions will be evaluated in order and will return False once any test in the line returns as False (or 0, or `[]` or `{}` etc.). You can see that with a test that would raise an error if python actually tried it.

```
x = 1; y = 2
if x < y and x == y and d['a']: # d doesn't exist
    print 'This will never be printed'
```

If your code isn't working as intended, please elaborate on exactly what you expect it to do, and what it is actually doing.

Comment: +1 for a good example, showing that the code after the short circuit is never even evaluated (since this would raise an exception if it were).

Comment: Good example. Actually my code was evaluating right (not working because of other mistakes). Interesting that non-existing objects are evaluated to False instead of raising an error. Thanks, +1!

Comment: @heltonbiker That's not quite true; if something is accessed that doesn't exist, it will return an error, not False. In my code `d['a']` doesn't raise an error because it is never evaluated. Python stops as soon as it gets to `x == y`, because that is False, which means my whole chain of `and`s is False. It doesn't bother checking the last term because it doesn't have to. If it did, an error would be raised. This is what people mean when they're talking about 'short-circuit' functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean and operator in Python (and most other programming languages) provides "short-circuit" functionality.  This means, that if the fist term or the expression evaluates to false, the second term is not even evaluated:

```
>>> False and expensiveFunctionReturningBool()
False
```

The expensive function will never be called, because the Python interpreter immediately evalues the expression as False after the first term is determined to be False.  This works, because in boolean logic, if one side of an and expression is false, the whole expression is false by definition

Python also uses short-circuit logic for or.  In this case, if the first term is determined to be True, the second term is never evaluated.

```
>>> True or expensive()
True
```

Thus, boolean expressions can be used to collapse nested if statements (provided they are declared immediately one after another), and if they are used cleverly by keeping short-circuit logic in mind, they can also optimize conditional expressions.

Good Luck!

Comment: I think you mean `True or expensive()`. I tried to edit but it wouldn't let me because the edit was < 6 characters.

Comment: I added "provided they are declared immediately one after another". The strategy proposed is very fine.

Comment: Thanks, @heltonbiker and Joel Cornett.  Can't believe I wrote "and" immediately after talking about or.... <facepalm>  =]

Answer (score 1):

I made some assumptions about the code you did not include and added it to get the program running:

```
gotside = False
j = 2
i = 1
unit = 3

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.shape = [1, 4]
    def __getitem__(self, pos):
        return pos

a = A()


if (not gotside):
    if (j > 1):
        if (j < a.shape[1] - 1):
            if a[i, j+unit]:
                print("only now I do stuff!")

if (not gotside) and (j > 1) and (j < a.shape[1] - 1) and a[i, j+unit]:
   print("I'm well tested but not so indented...")
```

For me this works with python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and 3.2:

```
only now I do stuff!
I'm well tested but not so indented...
```

Can you please check the above program if this works for you? If so, can you please give more information about the classes you use - especially the class of variable `a`.

Comment: I thank you very much for your code. Actually the mentioned code was working, there were other assert failures elsewhere in my program. Anyway, I think these answers, your included, might help people with similar doubts, in the future. Thanks again. +1